# Cannot access the AbortButton while doing background operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

my requirement is need to abort the backgroundworker operation while click abort button in alertbox(attached image[Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByFNc.jpg)). Because GetData() will take more time to execute.

if Dowork method is called no need to access the UI element which means we need to restrict that until the backgroundworker completed.So I put Application.Current.Dispatcher. If I remove that(Application.current.dispatcher) line we can access UI elements and do perform some actions, but we need to restrict that while perform dowork event.

Any solution for this,

```
     try
        {
            var backGroundWorker = new CancelSupportedBackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var alertBox = new AlertBox
            {
                IsBusy = true,
                WaitingText ="Export Data"
                WaitingHeaderText ="Exporting"
            };
            alertBox.AbortButton.Click += (obj, args) =>
            {
                source.Cancel();
                backGroundWorker.CancelAsync();
                backGroundWorker.Abort();
                backGroundWorker.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();
            };
            backGroundWorker.DoWork += (obj, args) =>                 
            {    
            Appliction.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(
                delegate
                {
                    table = GetData((CancellationToken)args.Argument);

                    if (source.Token != default(CancellationToken))
                        if (source.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                            return;
                    }));
             };
            backGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, args) =>
            {
                alertBox.IsBusy = false;
            };
           backGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(source.Token);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

I made an edit, passing an token argument to Dowork event

Clear Requirement is:

1) query operation is need to run in background

2) We cannot access the Other UI elements like File menu items

3) Access only the abort button in alertbox while performing query

If abort button is clicked it will automatically cancel the background operation.

I made an edit using Task.Run() method

```
     Task backgroundTask = null;
      try
        {

            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var alertBox = new AlertBox
            {
                IsBusy = true,
                WaitingText ="Export Data"
                WaitingHeaderText ="Exporting"
            };
            alertBox.AbortButton.Click += (obj, arg) =>
            {
                source.Cancel();
                GC.Collect();
            };
         backgroundTask = Task.Run(() => table =  GetFullData(source.Token));
         IWorkBook.ImportDataTable(table, true, 1, 1, true);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {

        }
```

I made an change for adding GetFullData() method

```
 internal DataTable GetFullData(CancellationToken token)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();


        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        if (QueryParameters != null && QueryParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in QueryParameters)
            {
                var param = command.CreateParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@" + parameter.Name.TrimStart('@');
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Value))
                {
                    param.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    param.Value = parameter.Value;
                }

                command.Parameters.Add(param);
            }

            command.GetPreparedSql();
        }

        command.Connection = connection;
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
       if (token != default(CancellationToken))
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        dataTable.Load(reader);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: I also try with replace the Application.current.Dispatcher into Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher. Here i can access the Other UI elements. But we need to restrict this while perform dowork event

Comment: BackgroundWorker is a very old pattern. The preferred pattern in .Net now is to use Task<TResult> with IProgress<T> to update the UI.

Comment: I don't need to update UI.Just want to call the abort click event while performing some operation in background. Any Link for Task<TResult> with IProgress<T>.

Comment: IProgress is not just for updating the UI, it is a simpler pattern that capture the context of the thread that created the Progress<T> instance, and allows you to register a callback that runs in the context of that thread. You create an instance of Progress<T>, passing in your Action callback that calls your abort click event handler. You then pass that IProgress object into the callback in Task.Run, Parallel.ForEach, etc. When you call IProgress.Report, your callback runs in the correct context.

Comment: You go to all of the effort of setting up a background worker but then immediately turn around and try to get all of its work to happen back on the UI thread by using the `Dispatcher`. Not sure why.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Assume if you are a user, you want to cancel the operation which will take more time to load. So that all effort are go to **background worker**. At the same time while doing background worker user cannot do perform any other operations until it will be completed. So **Dispatcher** is present

Comment: The Task.Run code looks good. Please post the code for GetFullData, it would help to see what's going on in there.

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working when you run this code using Task.Run.

Comment: If I run this code using Task.Run the abort click event is not hit while click button(Refer above image in Question)

Comment: Your problem is in the GetFullData method. You are passing the CancellationToken in, but you are not checking it periodically within this method & throwing a OperationCanceledException. So your outer code is async, but when you call this method it runs synchronously within the outer async call & does not listen for any about. Sprinkle a few token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() calls through this method at appropriate times like the body of loops. You can also cancel before command.ExecuteReader or dataTable.Load

Comment: Even though your abort handler is marking the token for cancellation, once you're in GetFullData, it doesn't listen for cancellation & runs start to finish

Comment: Exciting Now Abort click event is will be hit. But at same time we need to restrict the other UI elements while performing Task.Run().Here table value will be null for ImportTable() because it will call before completing GetFullData().

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict UI elements"? Do you mean prevent the user clicking on them or interacting with them? Or prevent your code accessing them?

Comment: It means, just you imagine one application like visual studio. It contains lot of Menu items. If user click export option the alertbox will be open and process for exporting is done in background. At time we need to restrict the user for doing anything.After completed background operation the alertbox will be closed. Here **Prevent the user clicking other than abort button**

Comment: What UI are you using? Winforms, WPF, HTML, ???

Comment: @AshleyPillay, I am using WPF UI

Comment: When you show the AlertBox form, can't you just disable the calling form?

Comment: Before executing the **dowork** method the alertbox will be open using **IsBusy** property and if it is completed(**RunWorkerCompleted method**) then disable that alertbox.

Comment: If I remove the Dispatcher line it will work perfectly. But one of my requirement is restrict other actions until it is completed. So using that dispatcher. Is any other way for doing this?

Comment: I don't mean disable the alertbox, I mean disable the form that launched the action. Just leave it on screen but set the form's enabled state to disabled/false. That will prevent the user interacting with the form until the alertbox closes & then you enable the parent form again

Comment: disbale the form is one of solution for this.But i think which is not propered solution.

Comment: That's exactly what the Windows API does when you show a form modally against a parent form.

Comment: You're looking for a "proper solution" if you're only exposed to modern high level languages like c# where you never see the implmentation of the .Net Framework & Base Class Library. If you had written C code for the Windows API directly, you'd see there's nothing improper about this approach. It's what Windows itself does for modal windows.

Comment: I added some extra code to show how to disable the owner form. This prevents the user clicking any controls on the form. It does allow them to drag & resize the owner form, being WPF, but I always wanted this ability in WinForms so it's a plus for me. If you want to disable this it's possible just google "wpf prevent window drag". The only thing you need to watch for is that they can close the owner form & therefore the alertbox, but you can easily add abort handlers for this.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your code in more detail, it looks like you don't need IProgress.

If you want to call any code on another thread, you should look at it, but just based off the question, you just need to use `Task.Run` & `CancellationToken`.

This code assumes a form called `frmDoWork` with 2 buttons `cmdDoWork` and `cmdAbort`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmDoWork : Form
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = null;
        Task backgroundTask = null;

        public frmDoWork()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WorkToDoInBackgroundThread(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Task.Delay(1000).Wait(cancellationToken);
                    progress.Report(i);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{i} - {DateTime.Now}");
                }
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
            {

            }

        }

        private void cmdDoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Progress <int> prg= new Progress<int>(x => this.Text = $"Iteration - {x}");

            backgroundTask = Task.Run(()=> WorkToDoInBackgroundThread(prg, cts.Token));
        }

        private void cmdAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts?.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to check whether the Task is already running & decide what to do if it is (cancel or wait). This really just means checking if cts is null if you reset it to null once the Task is fininshed.

You can also handle the cancelled exception however you want. This code just exits.

I made an edit to also show how to use the IProgress interface to make callbacks against another thread.

Here's a snippet to disable the owner form when you show the alert box. Adapt to your needs.

```
{
    AlertBox alertBox = new AlertBox();
    alertBox.Owner = this;
    alertBox.Show();
    alertBox.Closed += (sender, e) => this.IsEnabled = true;
    this.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ashley, I also using same concept as per your code. In my code, the abort button is clicked the background operation is will be cancelled. While using Application.current.Dispatcher line it will not be hit.This is our problem. Anyway i will try this

Comment: I understand the code looks similar but unless you're dealing with badly written legacy code that you are afraid of breaking, Tasks are the modern way of doing this. If you really want to stick with BackgroundWorker, I would suggest you use the overload of RunWorkerAsync which takes an argument. You can use that object to pass in whatever objects you need to call in backGroundWorker.DoWork and access them via the args parameter. Then you will not depend on Application.Current.Dispatcher since the objects will be directly accessible in the background thread.

Comment: I change code as per your suggestion for passing argument(Source.Token) to Dowork method is not worked as expected.

Comment: I try Task.Run() which also not working as expected.

Comment: By not working as expected, I assume you mean not aborting when you click the button. Please post the code you tried with Task.Run

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Finally i found the solution for this with the help of isHitTestVisible property which is used to return the hit test result of some portion.

Thanks @Ashley Pillay for your responses.

```
      Window.isHitTestVisible = false;
      alertBox.AbortButton.Click += (obj, args) =>
        {
            Window.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            source.Cancel();
            backGroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            backGroundWorker.Abort();
            backGroundWorker.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        };
        backGroundWorker.DoWork += (obj, args) =>                 
        { 
                table = GetData((CancellationToken)args.Argument);

                if (source.Token != default(CancellationToken))
                    if (source.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
         };
        backGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, args) =>
        {
            Window.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            alertBox.IsBusy = false;
        };
```

Comment: Just be aware the IsHitTestVisible is basically telling the window to ignore mouse events in it's client area. The window can still receive keyboard events & also mouse events in the non-client area (border). A user can click on the window & tab to various controls or Alt to menus. Also, there's no visual indication that the controls are not available. They look clickable, but just ignore clicks. Setting IsEnabled prevents both keyboard & mouse input, and also greys out child controls giving visual feedback the window cannot be interected with.

Comment: Thanks @AshleyPillay it will be work fine as set isEnabled as false.